# How to feed array into a TensorFlow placeholder correctly

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to feed the array in batches into Tensorflow placeholders. But even after providing correct shape I am getting an `InvalidArgumentError`.

Here is the part of my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

xdata = np.linspace(1,50, 10000)
noise = np.random.rand(len(xdata))
y_true = (1.5*xdata) + 5 + noise    #m = 1.5 and c = 5

m = tf.Variable(0.1)  #initial values
c = tf.Variable(0.2)

batch_size = 10

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size])

y_hat = (m*x) + c
error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y-y_hat))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate= 0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(error)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    n_batches = 1000

    for i in range(n_batches):

        rand_int = np.random.randint(len(xdata), size =batch_size)
        feed_dict = {x:xdata[rand_int], y: y_true[rand_int]}

        sess.run(train, feed_dict = feed_dict)
        print('Batch:',i, ' loss: ', sess.run(error))

    m_final, slope_final = sess.run([m , c])
```

The error is:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for  placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder' with dtype float  and shape [10]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in this line:

```py
print('Batch:', i, ' loss: ', sess.run(error))
```

In order to compute the value for tensor `error`, you must feed a value for placeholders `x` and `y`:

```py
sess.run(error, feed_dict)
```